# remove single object in storage

Tags: angular, ionic2

i have a json object on clicking add to cart in listing page a single object would get added up, and in cart page on clicking remove i need to delete that single object

**listing.html file**

```
<button ion-button full style="background-color: black" (click)="addTocart(item)">Add To Cart </button>
```

**listing.ts file**

```
    // my import statement
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
    export class OneProduct {  storedItem = []; any; }
     constructor( public storage: Storage) {
    //add to cart function
    addTocart(item) {
             this.storage.get('item').then((data) => {
                console.log(data)

                if (data != null) {

                 this.storedItem.push(item);
                 this.storage.set('item', this.storedItem);
                }else{
                    console.log("else")
                    this.storage.set("item", item);
                }
             })
          // this.nav.push(CartPage, { item: item });
        }
     }
```

the object gets added up to the storage, and in cart page i need to delete a single object from that storage so if 3 items added to cart and in cart page 2nd item is deleted then 1st and 3rd item should be visible

```
 <button block full ion-button color="dark" (click)="eliminate(cartitem)" > Eliminate</button>
```

**ts file**

```
 eliminate(cartitem){      
    this.storage.get('item').then((data) => {   
       var items = data;
        for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++ ){
            console.log(items[i])
            if (cartitem.id === items[i].id) {
               // console.log(cartitem.id);
               // console.log(items[i]);
              this.storage.remove( items[i]);
            }else{
                console.log("else statement");
            }
        } 
    })             
}
```

[image]

Could someone help me to achieve my goal, And suggest me weather the above storage is good or not while working with objects, i am trying to design a flipkart app.

Comment: try using sql lite storage and since you already have the object store so in cart page try comparing the id of the current object with the available stored object it that way you can get the object that you wanted to delete

Comment: check the updated @suraj

Answer (score 0):

You must pass to remove the 'key' of the object, not the whole object.
The code would look like this:

```
this.storage.remove(items[i].id);
```